Is it possible to make Microsoft Flow based on an existing flow?
Is it possible to make Microsoft Flow based on an existing flow by simply copy and pasting the flow or saving it under another name?  I want to make a virtually identical Microsoft Flow with the only difference being the destination Microsoft List that I am using as a database.
This is a short question.  But I think there is not much that needs to be explained.  If you need more clarificiation, please let me know.
There is a "Save" button but I do not see any "Save As" option.
There is a feature to use AI (so it is presented) in order to make a flow.  The user is supposed to describe the flow he wants and the AI Copilot is supposed to generate the new flow.  I tried this.  I asked it directly to make a clone of my existing Microsoft Automated Flow and provided a URL link to the existing Flow I wanted to make a copy from.  It was poo.  And yet it promised that it was thinking about it for so long in coming up with something.  
But it was all a lie.  It was not working on anything.  The resulting flow was set to be kicked off by a button.  It got everything wrong.
So I resorted to doing it by scratch and I was able to redo the same steps to a point.  It allowed me to do what I needed for the most part but when I wanted to add something more specific in advanced settings, it said that my flow was read-only.  Please advise.  Please help.


To clarify - are you missing these buttons?
https://i.sstatic.net/TMtNuCNJ.png

Long story short, you should be able to export (and import) the flow by simply replacing /details with /export in Flow detail URL.
Example:
Flow Detail URL:
https://make.powerautomate.com/environments/Default-f00e1111-2222-4b61-3333-55555503a4444/flows/e7140000-1111-444f-0000-3aadb12345acc/details
Flow Export URL:
https://make.powerautomate.com/environments/Default-f00e1111-2222-4b61-3333-55555503a4444/flows/e7140000-1111-444f-0000-3aadb12345acc/export

The reason you may not see the Save As option is that your flow may be solution based, for example.
